# NPM gets stuck when instally packages globally

Tags: node.js, cordova, windows-10, npm-install, cordova-cli

NPM when installing globally (-g option) gets stuck 
npm install -g cordova[image]

I have tried removing the entire nodejs and reinstalling etc. It installs if i try it locally to a folder but globally it fails.

I use a windows 10 recently updated to build 10.0.16299.125 . I use node version 8.9.3. I have also run the Command screen as **Administrator**

Answer (score 0):

Update node to Version 9.2.0

[Node Update on windows Tutorial](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade)

Comment: Doesnt work still. Is it possible to install cordova non globally and still run cordova related commands from the cli ? that is cordova not installed globally ?For example install crdova in folder x then in command navigate to x folder and run crodva build /add platform etc commands ?

Comment: @user581157 are you using ionic with it? And if yes then which version

Comment: Are you trying to install ionic in system32. Please run command from else where!

Comment: He is installing it globally.. so no point on changing the folder there :P